# Errors when trying to add ref to an overloaded method's parameter

Tags: c#

Why do I get the following to errors when I try to add `ref` to an overloaded method's parameter?

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.SearchProducts(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref
>   System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'int'

Here's some (simplified) code:

```
public virtual IList<int> SearchProducts(int categoryId)
{
    List<int> categoryIds = new List<int>();
    if (categoryId > 0)
        categoryIds.Add(categoryId);
    return SearchProducts(ref categoryIds);
}

public virtual IList<int> SearchProducts(ref IList<int> categoryIds)
{
    return new List<int>();
}
```

**Edit:**

Some of you asked me why I need `ref` in this case and the answer is that I probably don't need it, because I can clear the list and add new elements (I don't need to create a new reference). But the question is not about the fact that I need or don't need `ref`, it's about why I got the errors. And since I didn't find an answer (after googling for little while) I thought the question was interesting and worth asking here. It seems that some of you don't think it's a good question and voted to close it down ...

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear why you need to use `ref` in this case

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: The OP clearly stated that the code has been simplified.  How he is using `ref` is tangential to the topic.

Comment: @Ed S.: since I was here, just wanted to check if he's misunderstanding what `ref` would do. It seems to me that he's misusing it so I could remove his problem removing `ref` in first place :)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: Sure, it's a good comment (and I thought the same), but he said it has been simplified so I figured i'd leave it alone.  That said... I didn't need to comment back at you either :D

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I probably don't need `ref`, but that's not what the question is about (see edit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you pass an argument by reference, the compile-time type has to be the *exact* same type as the parameter type.

Suppose the second method was written as:

```
public virtual IList<int> SearchProducts(ref IList<int> categoryIds)
{
    categoryIds = new int[10];
    return null;
}
```

That must compile, as `int[]` implements `IList<int>`. However, it would break type safety if the caller *actually* had a variable of type `List<int>`, which now had a reference to an `int[]`...

You can fix this by making the declared type of `categoryIds` in the calling method `IList<int>` instead of `List<int>` - but I *strongly* suspect you don't actually want to pass the argument by reference in the first place. It's relatively rare to need to do so. How comfortable are you with [C# parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)?

Comment: @EdS.: There's a surprise :) I've voted to close now too, but I'll leave this answer in case it's helpful to the OP to see it applied in his context.

Comment: Yeah I actually removed the comment and upvoted because it is simpler and complimentary

Comment: I upvoted but then read Ed S. response and darnit Skeet, you have enough points already! :P Not that sharing with Eric Lippert is particularly spreading the wealth.. heh

Comment: @JonSkeet What you suspect is right, so thanks for pointing out that I `don't actually want to pass the argument by reference in the first place`. (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public virtual IList<int> SearchProducts(int categoryId)
{
    IList<int> categoryIds = new List<int>();
    if (categoryId > 0)
    categoryIds.Add(categoryId);
    return SearchProducts(ref categoryIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the method an assignable IList(of int).

```
IList<int> categoryIds = new List<int>();
```